# Using dbt macro in if else statement

Tags: if-statement, macros, dbt

I created a dbt macro `is_date_format.sql` that checks if a `source_value` resembles a simple date format `yyyy-mm-dd` (more specifically i compare the `source_value` to a regex pattern):

```
{% macro is_date_format(source_value) %}
    
    regexp_instr('{{source_value}}', '^[0-9]{4}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}$') > 0

{% endmacro %}
```

I am calling this macro in an if-else-statement:

```
{% if is_date_format(source_value) %}

    true

{% else %}

    false

{% endif %}
```

Somehow, this does not seem to work, because even if I am using a simple string (e.g. `'hello_world'`) the if-else-statement always ends up with true. The regex pattern works when testing it isolated. Only when I am using an if-else-statement this seems to be broken.

Can someone help me with that?

Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't think you can use a macro as a function inside a jinja statement like that - the typical use case for a macro is to dynamically generate some SQL. If "source_value" is a piece of data from a database table you might want to consider using native database functions to check for a valid date or do a regex comparison.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer :) 
I was thinking the same thing and I just have to use SQL then.

Answer (score 0):

We can replace the regular expression to check the date format inside macro for example : you can put format whatever you want to check DD/MM/YYYY or depending your need
I am checking dates directly inside macro and it's working fine.

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your answer. 
Can you give me an example for that? I am not sure how I can check the date format in a jinja if statement.

Comment: %Macro cast_date(column_name, curr_pattern)%.  Cast (column_name) as date format '(curr_pattern) end macro. Then you call inside you code example : select cast_date (column_name, 'DD/MM/YYYY') fromtable

Answer (score 0):

%Macro cast_date(column_name, curr_pattern)%. Cast (column_name) as date format '(curr_pattern) end macro. Then you call inside you code example : select cast_date (column_name, 'DD/MM/YYYY') fromtable

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the return statement inside the macro.

```
{% macro is_date_format(source_value) %}    
    return regexp_instr('{{source_value}}', '^[0-9]{4}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{2}$') > 0
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly, this didn't work for me. I don't think, that the return function of dbt works with SQL code but only with static values (see https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/return).